# get result in parent component after selectAll and unSelectAll event emitted from child (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am now working on angular to build a multiselect dropdown using ng-multiselect-dropdown(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown).

I used parent-child component communication through event emitter:
in child.component.ts:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {IDropdownSettings} from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';

export interface IMultiDropdownConfig {
  placeholder: string;
  header: string;
  dropdownSettings: IDropdownSettings;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-multi-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './multi-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multi-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class MultiDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dropdownItems: any[];

  @Input() selectedItems;

  @Input() header: string;

  @Input() placeholder: string;

  @Input() dropdownSettings: IDropdownSettings;

  @Input() loading;

  @Output() itemSelectEvent = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() itemDeselectEvent = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() selectAllEvent = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() deselectAllEvent = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() selectedItemsChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSelectItem(event) {
    this.selectedItemsChange.emit(this.selectedItems);
  }
  onDeselectItem(event) {
    this.selectedItemsChange.emit(this.selectedItems);
  }
  onSelectAll(event) {
    this.selectedItemsChange.emit(this.selectedItems);
  }

  onDeselectAll(event) {
    this.selectedItemsChange.emit(this.selectedItems);
  }
}
```

in child.component.html:

```
<div class="multi-dropdown-item">
  <div class="multi-dropdown-header">{{header}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="!this.loading" class="multi-dropdown-body">
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
      [placeholder]="placeholder"
      [data]="dropdownItems"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
      [settings]="dropdownSettings"
      (onSelect)="onSelectItem($event)"
      (onDeSelect)="onDeselectItem($event)"
      (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
      (onDeSelectAll)="onDeselectAll($event)">
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in parent.component.html:

```
          <app-multi-dropdown
            [loading]="filterPropertiesMap.get(filterEntry).loading"
            [dropdownItems]="filterPropertiesMap.get(filterEntry).items"
            [(selectedItems)]="filterPropertiesMap.get(filterEntry).selectedItems"
            [dropdownSettings]="filterPropertiesMap.get(filterEntry).setting"
            [placeholder]="filterPropertiesMap.get(filterEntry).name"
            [header]="filterPropertiesMap.get(filterEntry).name"
            (itemSelectEvent)="onItemSelect($event)"
            (itemDeselectEvent)="onItemDeselect($event)"
            (selectAllEvent)="onSelectAll($event)"
            (deselectAllEvent)="onDeselectAll($event)"

          ></app-multi-dropdown>
```

in parent.component.ts I didn't do anything but log:

```
  onItemSelect($event) {
    console.log("onItemSelect");

  }
  onItemDeselect($event) {
    console.log("onItemDeselect");

  }

  onSelectAll($event) {
    console.log("onSelectAll");

  }

  onDeselectAll($event) {
    console.log("onDeselectAll");

  }
```

in above code `filterPropertiesMap` defines settings.
You may see that what I am doing is in child component, I created eventemitters for select, deselect, and in the function I emitt `this.selectedItems`.

But I don't think this is a good way to implement this, and actually, it doesn't work well.
sometimes, when I select or deselect, it doesn't changed immediately.

**So how to implement this? when I select deselect, selectAll, deselectAll. my parent component can react immediately and correctly.**

Also the weird thing is: when I load the page, I will have some default values chose, for example 6,7,8,9. Then I select all and it still 6,7,8,9. and then after that I deselect all agin select all, the field will change to all(for example 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). **Does event emitter has delay or will ignore some choices??**

Edit:

I tried to extract all the necessary snippets of code to build a project here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BlV2EtdwZhqqpkdiC0_mlaw_r3w6Bder/view?usp=sharing

I hope when I all the event(select, deselect, selectAll, deselectAll) can be emitted and received by parent component

**sorry one mistake:** the app-multi-dropdown tag in parent component should be **app-child**

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, I set a working example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as part of an Angular reactive form, and just emit every time it value changes.

The HTML of the child component could be something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
        name="dropdownItems"
        [settings]="dropdownSettings"
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
        [data]="dropdownItems"
        formControlName="dropdownItems">
   </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</form>
```

And the .ts file:

```
import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Input() defaultValues: any[];
    @Input() dropdownItems: any[];
    @Input() dropdownSettings: IDropdownSettings;
    @Output() onDropdownChange = new EventEmitter();
    
    myForm: FormGroup;
    
    constructor(
        private _fb: FormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            dropdownItems: ['']
        });

        // Set default values as real values
        this.onDropdownChange.emit(this.defaultValues);

        this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            this.onDropdownChange.emit(val.dropdownItems)
        })
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Based on your last update:**

With the code you updated and my peace of code, I build this functional project running on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7w3dz

Hope I got the logic properly

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer, I am trying it. but I want to ask one question, in my code that I uploaded, why i choose 'Select All' and click button, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Your code doesn't look bad... the issue seems to be related to https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues/168, basically someone reported: "SelectAll and DeSelectAll options are not updating the parameter passed with ngModel" which is your case.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't set up your emitter properly. do this:

```
@Output()selectAllEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

onSelectAll(event) {
  this.selectAllEvent.emit(this.selectedItems);
}
```

then on the parent:

```
<app-multi-dropdown
   (selectAllEvent)="onSelectAll($event)"
></app-multi-dropdown>
```